# Connecting Temperature sensor EVAL board (ADT7516) to the BeagleBone Green

Tags: sensor, embedded, beaglebone-black, beagleboard, beaglebone

I have a BeagleBone Green

[image: Image of BeagleBone]

and an evaluation board of the temp sensor (ADT7516).

[image: Image if ADT7516]

I also have a 4-pin female jumper to grove 4 pin conversion cable.

I am not an electronics student and have no idea how to make the connection.
I would like to have some reference for the connection.
My goal is to write the driver for the ADT7516 and to test it accordingly.
Also, I don't want to use a breadboard here.
So can anyone help me with the connection here.

Thanks

Comment: So, do you have a question?

Comment: Hi Andy, I would like to know that how can I connect this. I've really got no idea for it's connection

Comment: Well, I see both have a USB port so I'd explore that option first.

Comment: Yes, though if you're going to try USB, maybe first try it on a desktop linux PC and then port the solution to the embedded Linux board.  Or figure out how to bypass the USB interface chip on the eval board and operate the sensor itself as an I2C or SPI peripheral.

Comment: Eval kits usually have a user guide. Did you read it already? If not, you should do that first, because you will see what interfaces the chip and the board have. Then you can compare with the interfaces that are available for the grove connector and see if you have a match.

Comment: @MarcoZollinger yes I have read the user guide but it seems that it tells about taking readings from the userspace with the help of a software. I don't want to do that. I want to connect the sensor with the evaluation board and then I'll first go for I2C peripheral for testing the driver. Right now, my goal is to be able to talk to the sensor with sysfs.

Comment: @ChrisStratton, I am going with I2C peripheral right now. But I don't understand that how can I connect BB and evaluation board. For understanding the BB, I tried to connect the digital light sensor with the BB and took the readings. That was quite simple as I just connected the  grove sensor directly with the board. But here I am not able to figure it out that how to connect these. If I connect both, BB and EVAL board through the usb then how will they talk to each other.

Comment: This will be mostly a software problem, and you are going to have to do a lot of reading and research on your own.  If you go with the USB, you need to understand how that works on a PC and how to port it - especially if the example is only for Windows and not Linux.  Likely the USB interface chip is something common from FTDI or similar, so you only need to figure out how it is used, not how to talk to it.  Either way, you're then going to need software to perform the appropriate operations on the ADT to configure it and get readings. This is your task, not something that fits in a question.

Comment: @ChrisStratton my basic question is that how to connect these two i.e. Do I just have to connect them with the PC through usb cable and then do something to get them talk or is there any wiring that I'll have to do here. My mentor told me to use jumper wires here. So if it is about wiring then I would like to know that how can I do it. I don't see any reference on internet to do so and hence I came here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can't find any documentation about how the communication over USB works, connecting the devices by I2C will probably be your best bet indeed.

- First one should check if the signal voltages of the Beaglebone and the Eval kit are the same. The silkscreen marking on the Beaglebone says 3V3, and if you have a look at the Beaglebone system reference manual, you will see that it is indeed 3.3V for its I/O pins and also the grove connector.
  Then you have to check for the Eval kit. In the schematic part with the sensor (ADT7516) you can see that its supply is tied to +3.3V. So the voltages check out.
- Now you should be able to just connect the SCL, SDA and GND signals of the Beaglebone to the SCL, SDA and GND connectors on the Eval kit with jumper wires. Don't connect the Vcc/3V3 pins, supply each board seperately over USB.
- There is the possibility of the USB controller on the Eval kit disturbing the communication on the I2C bus, because not all devices are multi-master capable. If you feel like you are having problems with this come back here and we will talk about how to disable the USB controller.