# Accessing I2C address of ADT7516 ( Temp sensor )

Tags: sensor, analog, i2c, embedded, beaglebone-black

I have a BeagleBone Green and an EVAL board of ADT7516. I connected them by SDA and SCL pins and as they are to be connected with the PC by the usb port, they will have a common ground.

After this setup, I did i2cdetect -y -r which gives me the output as 0x51.

This address doesn't seem to be the address of the ADT7516 sensor. Instead, I can see that there is another part on the I2C bus, a serial rom chip 24lc64, which indeed has the I2C address as 0x51.

Page 11 - http://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/evaluation-documentation/512585584eval_adt7516eb.pdf

But my goal here is to be able to talk to the temp sensor ADT7516. I tried out to ask for some help on IRC and google groups and they said that it might be possible that the mux which is connected to the temp sensor is sending things in a wrong way. - page 11 of the datasheet

How can I talk to the adt7516 sensor here?
Find out the picture of EVAL board [here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/383901/connecting-temperature-sensor-eval-board-adt7516-to-the-beaglebone-green).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you suspect, there is a chip in the way that might be preventing you to communicate with the sensor. The chip is the ADG774, I suspect it is U4 but I could not find the refdef in the schematic.

The IN pin of said chip must be tied low in order for S1A and S2A to be connected to D1 and D2. To achieve this, you have two ways: either you rework the board, forcing IN to gnd, or you find out how to generate such a signal with the big cypress USB chip. The PIN you must pull low is PD2.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I've also got one suggestion from IRC channel - solder onto the pin 1 of U4 ( the mux ) and connect it to ground. Before that, making sure that microcontroller is held in reset by  
bridging capacitor C15 by a solder blob. So what are your ideas on this?

Comment: If you give a look to my second paragraph, forcing IN to gnd is an option.

Comment: Yes! I was just confirming from you that whether the method described in my previous comment will be safe or not.